# How would I fetch variables from an URL and put it into my Database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, url

So I've looked up many tutorials on how to get variables like http://example.net/pb.php?id=1&affsub=stringhere&key=123abc and then when that page is accessed I want it to be put into my database. But I have tried doing so by using this piece of code. And when accessing the page using ?id=1&affsub=stringhere&key=123abc it doesn't show any errors on the page and it also doesn't put it in the database as well. Now I'm not sure what is happening or what I need to do for that to work.

```
<?
if( $_POST )
{
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");

  if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  mysql_select_db("tbl", $con);

  $id = $GET['id'];
  $affsub = $_GET['affsub'];
  $key = $_GET['key'];

  $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
  $affsub = mysql_real_escape_string($affsub);
  $key = mysql_real_escape_string($key);

  $query = "
  INSERT INTO `tbl`.`users` (`id`, `affsub`, `key`) VALUES ('$id',
        '$affsub', '$key');";

  mysql_query($query);

  echo "<h2>User added to system.</h2>";

  mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: 1. _stop_ using the outdated, long deprecated and insecure `mysql_...()` functions, port your code to `mysqli` or `PDO` _now_.

Comment: 2. You have to decide if you want to process a http post or a http get request, your current coded mixes both.

Comment: 3. There is a difference between `$GET` and `$_GET`...

Comment: 4. please read about the benefits of using "prepared statements" in combination with "parameter bindung" to prevent sql injection attacks.

Comment: 5. _Usually_ a user id is _not_ something the client provides, that would lead to chaos. Instead it is an internal technical usually generated by the database itself. That guarantees uniqueness and usability.

Comment: 6. and should have been 1. Closed as a duplicate.

Comment: 7. sure, but not before recommending to the OP to start monitoring the http servers error log file for more details information about what _precise_ error actually occurs.

Comment: @arkascha theres no error logs

Comment: An http server _always_ writes an error log file, _unless you explicitly disabled it_, which you should _never_ do.

Comment: it is activated but there are no error log

Comment: @arkascha - Typically I find that PHP application level errors are not written to the logs - e.g., 404, 500 (e.g., PHP file abend) yes, but MySQL coding, incorrect variable names, etc. no.

Comment: Invalid sql statements are definitely logged, "incorrect variables"... well what is that? Keep in mind that php is a dynamic language, so only syntactically invalid variables names can be considered invalid. But anyway, so you _do_ have an error log file with entries, but none of those entries is relevant here in your eyes.

Comment: Consider the other hints you were given, try to debug yourself step by step. There are many issues here, you will have to resolve them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is inside `if ($_POST)` so you need to to retrieve the data from `$_POST[]` instead of `$_GET[]` (and the typo. error `$GET['id']`). In addition, the parameters should not be in the URL - that would normally indicate a form using the get method but for updating a database you normally want to use `method="post"` in your form.

Comment: Considering the example URL the OP gave the desired values will _not_ be populated into the `$_POST` superglobal variable...

Comment: @arkascha - I missed that. You're right. So now we have a mix between (apparently) form method "get" (probably by default), if $_POST, trying to retrieve parameters with $_GET and a mistaken $GET. Oh what a mess...